# O programa 'ng' não está instalado no momento. Você pode instalá-lo digitando: sudo apt-get install ng-common

Tags: angular

Estou aprendendo a trabalhar com Angular e estou numa bronca aqui.

Estou tentando criar uma nova pasta usando o comando **`ng new "nome da pasta"`**, mas está aparecendo a mensagem

> O programa 'ng' não está instalado no momento. Você pode instalá-lo digitando: sudo apt-get install ng-common`

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7735#issuecomment-345546822

Comment: Tentei tudo isso, mas a mensagem continua aparecendo...

Comment: Talvez você precisa entrar no diretório certo. Já aconteceu comigo de as vezes eu não estar apontando pro diretório certo no prompt de comando e ter que voltar um ou avançar.